# Как в SASS правильно расписать вложенный тег?

Tags: css, вёрстка, sass, frontend

Есть список, `Item` которого являются ссылки

```
<ul class="list"> 
<li class="list-child"> 
<a> </a>
</li>
<li class="list-child"> 
<a> </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

В стилях сделал вложенность классов:

```
.list {
   .child-list{}
}
```

Думал,что можно вложить и `anchor`:

```
.list {
  .child-list{
    a{}
  }

}
```

, но `sass` ругается. Можно ли это сделать, или же надо отдельно писать стили в таких случаях?

Comment: Про Sass не знаю, но в Less такие конструкции работают. :) Переходите на Less.

Comment: пробовал,sass понарвился больше. нашел выход. можно так сделать .child-list{
           >a{}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sass ругается скорее всего из-за того, что вы не соблюдаете отступы и путаете их с табами.

Можно писать например так(`display:block` - для примера):

```
.list{
  display:block;
  &-child{
   display:block;
   a{
    display:block;
   }
  }
}
```

из этого получится

```
.list {
  display: block;
}
.list-child {
  display: block;
}
.list-child a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

нашел ответ,оставлю его тут,может кому пригодится.

```
.child-list{
           >a{}
}
```